# Use a progressbar twice with the same timer

Tags: vb.net

I want to use a progressbar twice with two different buttons one by one. The problem if after the first reaches max value it won't start again from the other button.

Here is the code :

```
Private Sub CrystalClearButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CrystalClearButton1.Click
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
End Sub

Private Sub CrystalClearButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CrystalClearButton2.Click
    Timer2.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to reset the value each time the button is clicked.

Here is one example:

```
Private Sub CrystalClearButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CrystalClearButton1.Click
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

Also, instead of setting to 0, you can ensure that if you change the `Minimum` property on the progress bar, this code will continue to work by using the following code (if you are always going to use 0 as a minimum, then the previous code will be fine):

```
ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Minimum
```

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow! Remember, if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark next to that answer. This will help future visitors to the question know that this answer solved your problem and will also improve your reputation on the site.